# where is the error in fake proof that a gaussian has 0 variance

Tags: probability, statistics, fake-proofs

Consider the exponential family $$p_\theta(dy) = h(y)\exp(\langle \theta,T(y)\rangle - \Phi(\theta))\mu(dy)$$ with $\theta \in \mathbb R^d$ and the partition function $\Phi(\theta)<\infty$ for all $\theta \in \mathbb R^d$.
Suppose $\nabla \Phi: (\mathbb R^d,\|\cdot\|_2) \to (\mathbb R^d,\|\cdot\|_2)$ is L-Lipschitz.

Fix any $v$ on the $d-1$ dimensional sphere. Then it can be shown $X = \langle v, T(Y)\rangle$ is $2L$ sub-Gaussian.

Now, consider the family $$p_\theta(dy) = \exp(-(y-\mu)^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}\,dy$$
This is an exponential family with $\theta = [\mu \mid \mu^2]$ and $T(y) = [y\mid -1/2]$.
But then this implies $$X = \langle e_1,T(Y)\rangle = Y$$
is $2L$ sub-Gaussian for every $L>0$ (since $\Phi(\theta) \equiv \log \sqrt{2\pi}$)

In a similar vein, by taking $\theta = [\mu \mid \mu^2 \mid -1/2]$ and $T(y) = [y \mid -1/2 \mid y^2]$, one can deduce the problematic statements that $Y^2$ is 1) sub-Gaussian, and 2) has zero variance.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first subcase, why is $\mu^2$ a parameter while it is not multiplied by any $y$? It seems that in your parameterization $\Phi$ depends implicitly on $y$. To see it explicitly: $\Phi(\mu) = .5\log 2\pi = -\langle e_2,T(y) \rangle \log 2\pi$.
The intuition is that $T(y)$ must be a vector of *sufficient statistics*, which obviously a constant is not.

A correct parameterization could be $\theta=\mu,T(y)=y, h(y)=\exp(-.5\times y^2)$ and $\Phi(\theta)=.5(\log2\pi+\mu^2)$. However, we then have $\nabla\Phi=\mu$, which is $L\geq 1$ Lipschitz, which makes sense for a Gaussian distribution with variance 1.

Edited: corrected for the problems pointed in the discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1) "why is $\mu^2$ a parameter while it is not multiplied by any $y$?" My understanding is that one has $\langle \theta,T(y)\rangle$, so $\mu^2$ need not be multiplied by any $y$. $T$ is a vector of statistics. Namely, it may only depend on $y$, but it need not depend on $y$. 2) "how you define $\nabla \Phi$ that must then include a differentiation with respect to 1/2?" Not sure what this means. 3) "Similarly a constant is not normally distributed$\dots$" not sure what this means either

Comment: Also, $\mu \mapsto \nabla \Phi(\mu) = \mu$ is not lipschitz?

Comment: I got confused the function is Lipschitz $L\geq1$

Comment: The issue is you are implicitly adding $1/2$ to the vector $y$ so now your function $\Phi$ depends on y implicitly.

Comment: To see it explicitly: $\Phi(\mu) = .5\log 2\pi = - \langle e_2,T(y) \rangle \log 2\pi$

Comment: The intuition is that $T(y)$ must be a vector of *sufficient statistics*, which obviously a constant is not.

Comment: I see, so $\Phi$ may not depend on $T$, whereas my choice of $\Phi$ depends on $T$, in a very subtle way. Thanks

Comment: Exactly, I apologize for the confused answer, and thank you for the interesting question!